# VoiceProcessThread crash webRTC

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, libjingle, starscream

My app crashes without any error log while calling gotICECandidate when remote candidates received.

[image]

The exception I got from server is this.

[image]

backtrace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #36, name = 'VoiceProcessThread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb00000001062662c)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100bee6d4 PortalApp`cricket::BaseChannel::SendPacket(bool, rtc::Buffer*, rtc::PacketOptions const&) + 204
    frame #1: 0x0000000100bbbdd0 PortalApp`cricket::MediaChannel::DoSendPacket(rtc::Buffer*, bool, rtc::PacketOptions const&) + 96
    frame #2: 0x0000000100be99a4 PortalApp`cricket::WebRtcVoiceMediaChannel::SendRtcp(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) + 108
    frame #3: 0x0000000100db528c PortalApp`webrtc::voe::Channel::SendRtcp(unsigned char const*, unsigned long) + 132
    frame #4: 0x0000000100d4de08 PortalApp`non-virtual thunk to webrtc::PacketContainer::OnPacketReady(unsigned char*, unsigned long) + 36
    frame #5: 0x0000000100d3f894 PortalApp`webrtc::rtcp::RtcpPacket::BuildExternalBuffer(unsigned char*, unsigned long, webrtc::rtcp::RtcpPacket::PacketReadyCallback*) const + 80
    frame #6: 0x0000000100d3f820 PortalApp`webrtc::rtcp::RtcpPacket::Build(webrtc::rtcp::RtcpPacket::PacketReadyCallback*) const + 60
    frame #7: 0x0000000100d4d228 PortalApp`webrtc::RTCPSender::SendCompoundRTCP(webrtc::RTCPSender::FeedbackState const&, std::__1::set<webrtc::RTCPPacketType, std::__1::less<webrtc::RTCPPacketType>, std::__1::allocator<webrtc::RTCPPacketType> > const&, int, unsigned short const*, bool, unsigned long long) + 596
    frame #8: 0x0000000100d4c614 PortalApp`webrtc::RTCPSender::SendRTCP(webrtc::RTCPSender::FeedbackState const&, webrtc::RTCPPacketType, int, unsigned short const*, bool, unsigned long long) + 112
    frame #9: 0x0000000100d3e2ec PortalApp`webrtc::ModuleRtpRtcpImpl::Process() + 972
    frame #10: 0x0000000100ea3d6c PortalApp`webrtc::ProcessThreadImpl::Process() + 188
    frame #11: 0x0000000100ceebb8 PortalApp`rtc::PlatformThread::Run() + 76
    frame #12: 0x0000000100ceeb60 PortalApp`rtc::PlatformThread::StartThread(void*) + 12
    frame #13: 0x00000001943e82c0 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 128
    frame #14: 0x00000001943e8220 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 44
    frame #15: 0x00000001943ebcdc libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Please provide crash report.

Comment: if i would be getting crash report, i would know the issue. but not getting any crash report too.

Comment: Try adding an exception breakpoint and see where it is getting crashed.

Comment: exception break point is stopping here shown in image.. so not able to get an idea.

Comment: @manishsharma93 I have added a screenshot for an error i'm getting from server. if that can help you to get idea.

Comment: In Xcode's lldb debugger, enter `bt` to get the backtrace and include that. Also please provide full console output as text.

Comment: @DougRichardson added

Comment: @DougRichardson does this trace helped?

Comment: Actually no, I'm more confused because this appears to be audio data being sent, but your initial bug description was about a log that occurred while getting ICE candidates, which should occur before any audio is sent.

Comment: Some thoughts though: 1) Is there any chance that you had an RTC session already setup when you tried to start a new one? 2) This could be a result of a memory management issue at a higher level (aka you released something that you shouldn't have released). Unfortunately, I don't know the library well enough to make a better guess than that.